# Count elements in product base in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have spreedsheet with product base, for example:

```
product_name; element_name; element_quantity
product_1; element_1; 5
product_1; element_2; 10
product_2; element_1; 2
product_2; element_3; 1
```

And products list, for example:

```
product_name; product_quantity
product_1; 5
product_2; 10
product_1; 1
```

What formulas should I use to get elements and it's quantity used to make products in list?
I have products database and after I fill list i want to make billing of elements with I have to buy.
If this is possible I dont want use Google Query because it's slow.

I want generate list like:

```
element_name; element_quantity
element_1; 50
element_2; 60
element_3; 10
```

My orginal base have around 200 products and 50 different elements.

This was my first solution but its slow and code is mess but only this works:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(
{
IF('LIST'!E2 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D2 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E3 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D3 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E4 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D4 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E5 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D5 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E6 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D6 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E7 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D7 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E8 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D8 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E9 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D9 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E10 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D10 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E11 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D11 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E12 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D12 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E13 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D13 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E14 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D14 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E15 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D15 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E16 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D16 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E17 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D17 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E18 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D18 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E19 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D19 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E20 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D20 &"'";1); {""\""\""});
IF('LIST'!E21 = FALSE; QUERY(furniture_accessories_base;"select B,C,E where A='" & 'LIST'!D21 &"'";1); {""\""\""})
};
"select Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3) where Col3 > 0 group by Col1, Col2 ORDER BY SUM(Col3) DESC LABEL SUM(Col3) 'QUANTITY'"); {"-"\"-"\"-"})
```

Comment: how did you calculate 50, 60, 10?

Comment: product_1 * 6:
element_1 5 * 6 = 30
element_2 10 * 6 = 60

product_2 * 10:
element_1 2 * 10 = 20
element_3 1 * 10 = 10

element_1 = 30 + 20 = 50
element_2 = 60
element_3 = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

H1: `=unique(E:E)`

K1: `=unique(B:B)`

I2: `=sumif(E:E,H2,F:F)`

L2: `=sumproduct(filter(C:C,B:B=K2),arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(filter(A:A,B:B=K2),H:I,2,0),0)))`

I could not get I2 and L2 as `arrayformulas`. So you'll need to copy those down the column.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for this solution, i have to adapt this a little to my problem but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B2:B, C2:C*VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({E2:F}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 !='' group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image: 0]